# Single or multiple Abstract Factories for creating objects in an inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, software-design, abstract-factory

I have the following health club scenario (coded in C++ BTW):

[image: UML Diagram]

I want to create random Guest and Trainer objects (so both would have names randomly generated, but the guest would also have random health data).

I want to be able to make a lot of different random generators of differing complexities.

So clearly both would need the random forename/surname generator functionality - but I'm not sure how I can keep this code in one place.

I could have an abstract factory with all generation methods (e.g. generateForename()) in it that all the objects that require random generation can use. But should a trainer have access to a factory that can generate health data even though it has nothing to do with them?

I also thought about having an abstract factory for each class - so one for person, one for customer, one for guest and have objects generate their superclasses by passing them the appropriate factory but that sounds over complex for the situation.

I am fairly new to this so forgive me if my design is a bit off.

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: abstract factory is for a family of abstract classes so perhaps one would suffice. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure an Abstract Factory is what you're looking for. An Abstract Factory works best when you have the same base class but you need to create different concrete instances. Although you have the root base class of Person, you actually need to create derivatives of two, different base classes.

I would endeavour to keep the methods that generate data together with the class that contains that data. This way it can be reused.

Could you create a factory method on Guest and Trainer that would then be able to use the methods in their respective base classes to generate the data? Maybe create test-specific sub-classes to keep test stuff away from real stuff?